# When annotating a class with @Component, does this mean it is a Spring Bean and Singleton?

Tags: spring, annotations

Being fairly new to Spring I have a question about annotating a class. When annotating a class with `@Component` does this mean this class will be a Spring Bean and by default a singleton?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, `@Component` is a Spring bean and a Singleton.

If the class belongs to the service layer you may want to annotate it with `@Service` instead

But have in mind that in order for these annotations to be detected, you need to place this line in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany" />
```

About singletons - spring beans are all in singleton scope by default. The only thing you have to have in mind is that you should not store state in field variables (they should only hold dependencies). Thus your application will be thread-safe, and you won't require a new instance of a bean each time. In other words, your beans are stateless.

Comment: When using the @Component and or @Service annotations etc.. means that i am creating Singletons, will i not run into concurrency issues? To my newbie idea it will results in a bean that is used throughout the ApplicationContext, so concurrent users will get a reference to the single bean. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @Marco if you don't have any state (instance variables different from spring beans), then no concurrency issues will occur.

Comment: you "want" require a new instance of a bean each time or you "wont" require a new instance of a bean each time?

Comment: @Bozho What do you mean by: "and you won't require a new instance of a bean each time"? Do mean that Spring won't have to create a new instance or you as a developer won't need to create a new instance?

Answer (score 44):

By default - Yes.

However, you can override this behavior using the `@Scope` annotation. For example: `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`